# Past participles having usage as Present tense words

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

The word **Found**, apart from being the past tense of Find, has another meaning as follows(verb): Establish or originate (an institution or organization) as in "Foundation of a building" or "Founder of a company".

Similarly, **Thought**, independent form the word Think, also means (noun): Product or outcome of mental activity as in "Thought for the day".

Though, these are Past participles of a verb, they are also used in the time frame of Present tense.

Is there any grammatical rule behind this concept of using Past participle words in present tenses? Are there any other such words?

(Edit) P.S.: I am not sure as to what aspect of 'Grammaticality' is involved in such usage and hence, am not able to make myself clear enough, I suppose.

Comment: "found" meaning to establish is unrelated etymologically to "found" the past tense of "to find"; they just happen to have developed to identical forms.

Comment: "thought" as a noun is related to think; i.e. the result of thinking is a thought (it has been thought).

Comment: The info about 'found' was helpful. But Thought is a Past Participle for Think and at the same time has a meaning in context to the Present. Are there any more words like this? And is there any rule behind this 'Thought-Think' concept.

Comment: It's similar to how passives work in general. A passive form can describe a current state OR the result of an action.

Comment: Does it happen to verbs in general? For the verb Build, the outcome becomes a Building, but this concept is categorised as Verbal Nouns. Do passive forms of other verbs become the result outcome?

Comment: Not in general.